# Extracting capturing group contents in Varnish regex

Tags: regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have the following regular expression in Varnish configuration language

```
^/abc/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\ ]*)-([0-9]+)
```

Now , I want fetch the value `$2` part(i.e `[0-9]+`) of regular expression in Varnish.

How can I get this value?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `regsub` in this case:

```
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/abc/([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)-([0-9]+).*", "\2");
```

You match the whole string, capture the part you need, and replace with the appropriate backreference.

Comment: it is not working in varnish4+ version it is giving error as : Symbol not found: 're.group.2' (expected type STRING_LIST)

Comment: @nr23: Did you add `import std;` at the top?

Comment: What is your input? Is it a string?

Comment: url like: www.example.com/abc/def-123

Comment: I checked it again and see that `regsub` should still work as expected. Also, could you please confirm if `$2` works? Like `if (req.url ~ "^/abc/([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)-([0-9]+)") {
  set req.http.Thing-I-Want = $2;
}`

Comment: i have one doubt in varnish storage process, i have specified file location to store cache in file system but when i removed that file it is still giving varnish request as hit why it is happening ????

Comment: @nr23: No idea, but cache related issues are usually solved after a system restart. Sorry, it is already another question, not related to this one.

Comment: Late to the party here, but I believe it should be `set req.http.Thing-I-Want = regsub(req.url, "^/abc/([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)-([0-9]+)", "\2")`