# Regex capture group in Varnish VCL

Tags: regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a URL in the form of:

`http://some-site.com/api/v2/portal-name/some/webservice/call`

The data I want to fetch needs

`http://portal-name.com/webservices/v2/some/webservice/call`

(Yes I can rewrite the application so it uses other URL's but we are testing varnish at the moment so for now it cannot be intrusive.)

But I'm having trouble getting the URL correctly in varnish VCL. The `api` part is replaced by an empty string, no worries but now the portal-name.

Things I've tried:

```
if (req.url ~ ".*/(.*)/") {
  set req.http.portalhostname = re.group.0;
  set req.http.portalhostname = $1;
}
```

From https://docs.fastly.com/guides/vcl/vcl-regular-expression-cheat-sheet and [Extracting capturing group contents in Varnish regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179243/extracting-capturing-group-contents-in-varnish-regex)

And yes, `std` is imported.

But this gives me either a

```
Syntax error at
('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 36 Pos 35)
    set req.http.portalhostname = $1;
```

or a

```
Symbol not found: 're.group.0' (expected type STRING_LIST):
```

So: how can I do this? When I have extracted the `portalhostname` I should be able to simply do a `regsub` to replace that value with an empty string and then prepend "webservices" and my URL is complete.

The varnish version i'm using: `varnish-4.1.8 revision d266ac5c6`

Comment: Try  `set resp.http.portalhostname = re.group.1;`

Comment: Thanks but same error, `Symbol not found: 're.group.1' (expected type STRING_LIST):`

Answer (score 2):

Sadly re.group seems to have been removed at some version. Similar functionality appears to be accessible via one of several vmods. See https://varnish-cache.org/vmods/